# JetBrains Intellij macOS light theme for iTerm2

Tags: themes, jetbrains-ide, iterm2

I am currently using the macOS Light theme in my IntelliJ.

When I press: System Preferences -> Appearance and Behavior -> Appearance -> Theme, I can see macOS Light. I am also using light mode on my machine.

I am quite interested in the same theme, but for iTerm2. I could not find anything on the web.

So I wanted to ask this quick question, what would be the iTerm2 settings in order to have the same theme/look in iTerm2 please?

Maybe there is an already available version to download for iTerm2?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exact theme in iTerm do you want, but I would suggest you got through the [iterm2colorschemes](https://iterm2colorschemes.com) website and then see if there is already a theme that matches your requirements.

If one of the theme matches your requirement, then install that theme into your iTerm and use.

If there is no theme which is exact to your requiremets, please select the nearest light theme and modify the colors in it using your iTerm2 settings.

[image: my iterm2 theme]

[image: Modify your colour theme as per your requirements]

Comment: Your terminal is really pretty! What theme is it?